# Java Interests loop with method

Tags: java, loops, methods

I have a method which calulates intrests.

```
public static float calculateIntrests (float Principal, float RateInPercentage){

float result;
result=Principal*RateInPercentage;


return result;
```

Now I need a loop to print me how much "money" do I have each year. I have done something like this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Aplikacija {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int years = 1;
        System.out.println("Principal!");
        float Principal = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Rate!");
        int Rate = input.nextInt();
        float RateInPercentage = Rate / 100.0f;
        float calculate = Caluclateintrests(Principal, rateinPercentage);

        while (year <= 5) {

            System.out.println("It is: " + (calculate) + " dollars in year" + year + "on your account");
            year++;

        }

        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You habe declared `years` but you use `year` in your loop. However, what is your question?

Comment: You also declare `RateInPercentage` but then use `rateInPercentage` (first letter capitalization). Is this code copy/pasted? There should be a number of compile errors.

Comment: And also declare `calculateIntrests` but then use `Caluclateintrests` (capitalization, again).

Comment: try to listen to your compiler first, it shows you what and where exactly you have a problem

Answer (score 0):

Java is a case sensitive, so if you declared `variable`, `method` or `class` with a specific name then you have to sick with the declared name in order to use it,

So you have declared `years` but you used `year` instead

```
int years = 1;
```

But used as:

```
while (year <= 5) {//
```

So here you can do two of thins:

1. change the declaration of years to be year.
2. change the using of that variable to years.

This also goes with `RateInPercentage` variable, `Caluclateintrests` method.

Answer (score 0):

You have lots and lots of mistakes. Remember to spell it right and that Java is case-sensitive, therefore you have to keep eye on capital letters.

---

And few mistakes are not syntax, but in logical matter.

---

Also the naming convention for Java suppose to start naming variables and methods with lower-case letter.

---

This is working code, try to learn from it :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Aplikacija {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int year = 1;
        System.out.println("Principal!");
        float principal = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Rate!");
        int rate = input.nextInt();
        float rateInPercentage = rate / 100.0f;        

        while (year <= 5) {
            principal += calculateIntrests(principal, rateInPercentage);
            System.out.println("It is: " + principal + " dollars in year" + year + " on your account");
            year++;

        }

        input.close();
    }

    public static float calculateIntrests(float principal, float rateInPercentage) {
        float result;
        result = principal * rateInPercentage;

        return result;
    }
}
```

---

Sample output :

```
Principal!
100
Rate!
1
It is: 101.0 dollars in year1 on your account
It is: 102.01 dollars in year2 on your account
It is: 103.030106 dollars in year3 on your account
It is: 104.06041 dollars in year4 on your account
It is: 105.10101 dollars in year5 on your account
```